# YouCompleteMe typescript error in vim

Tags: typescript, vim, youcompleteme

I just installed YouCompleteMe with typescript support. I followed the YCM installation guide and had installed typescript through 
    npm install -g typescript

Then I compiled YCM thru its install.py. Everything seems to be fine except the error marks. I cloned an angular example from angular office site which I am sure the sample is syntax-correct for sure. However every ts file comes with some error red marks at beginnings of lines and red highlighted words. There seem to be some errors in those lines. I didn't touch any of the files at all. Please help.
[Typescript erros](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM5YT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in Typescript 2.6.x due to the development team kinda releasing it into the wild without a leash. The autocomplete tool should work fine again if you go back to Typescript version 2.5.3

`sudo npm install -g typescript@2.5.3`

This worked for me. Hope it helps you, too.